# pgfmath function that puts out a question mark in some cases

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

[image]

I have a `pgfmath`-function here, that tests whether the `\Phase` is equal to 'gas', then the value `\Density` has to be multiplicated by 1000 (else not) and that's the `DensityShowTest`. That works so far.

Now there is the case, that the `\Phase` equal to 'unknown' and the `\Density` is equal to '-1' (which means unknown as well).

Here I would like to have a question mark as output for the DensityShowTest. At the moment he puts out '777'. If I replaced 777 by "?" it does not work.

What do I have to do?

*Note that a lot has been done with `pgfmath` in the main document, so I would like to work with a `pgfmath` solution.*

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{DensityShowTest}{2}{%
\pgfmathparse{dim("#1")==3}%
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
  \pgfmathparse{1000*#2}%
\else%
   \pgfmathparse{#2==-1 ? 777 : #2}% here is a "?" needed instead of 777 !!!
\fi}
% usage:
% \pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("gas", 0.0008)}\pgfmathresult 

\begin{document}
\xdef\Phase{liquid}  
\xdef\Density{1.23}  
\section{Phase: \Phase, Density is: \Density ~-- works}
Density show: 
\pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("\Phase", \Density)}\pgfmathresult 

\xdef\Phase{gas}  
\xdef\Density{0.00008}  
\section{Phase: \Phase, Density is: \Density ~-- works too}
Density show: 
\pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("\Phase", \Density)}\pgfmathresult 

\xdef\Phase{unknown}  
\xdef\Density{-1}% -1 means unknown <--- !  
\section{Phase: \Phase, Density is: \Density ~-- works not with a questionmark}
Density show: 
\pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("\Phase", \Density)}\pgfmathresult 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use strings in `pgfmath`.

```
\pgfmathparse{#2==-1 ? "?" : #2}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{DensityShowTest}{2}{%
\pgfmathparse{dim("#1")==3}%
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
  \pgfmathparse{1000*#2}%
\else%
   \pgfmathparse{#2==-1 ? "?" : #2}% here is a "?" needed instead of 777 !!!
\fi}
% usage:
% \pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("gas", 0.0008)}\pgfmathresult 

\begin{document}
\xdef\Phase{liquid}  
\xdef\Density{1.23}  
\section{Phase: \Phase, Density is: \Density ~-- works}
Density show: 
\pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("\Phase", \Density)}\pgfmathresult 

\xdef\Phase{gas}  
\xdef\Density{0.00008}  
\section{Phase: \Phase, Density is: \Density ~-- works too}
Density show: 
\pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("\Phase", \Density)}\pgfmathresult 

\xdef\Phase{unknown}  
\xdef\Density{-1}% -1 means unknown <--- !  
\section{Phase: \Phase, Density is: \Density ~-- works not with a questionmark}
Density show: 
\pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("\Phase", \Density)}\pgfmathresult 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Normally yes, but in this case, he does not accept that.... try this syntax out.

Comment: @cis Added full MWE and screenshot.

Comment: Works, TYVM. .......................................

Answer (score 4):

Problem is `\pgfmathparse` wants to operate on numbers, not symbols (`?`).  So I had to directly test for a string compare to `1.0` outside of pgf, using `\pdfstrcmp`.  I therefore had to incorporate `\pgfmathresult` directly into the macro.

As is, this works in pdflatex and xelatex.  For lua, you need the lua equivalent of etex's `\pdfstrcmp`.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{DensityShowTest}{2}{%
\pgfmathparse{dim("#1")==3}%
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
  \pgfmathparse{1000*#2}\pgfmathresult%
\else%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{-1.0} = 0?\else\pgfmathparse{#2}\pgfmathresult\fi
\fi}
% usage:
% \pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("gas", 0.0008)}

\begin{document}
\xdef\Phase{liquid}  
\xdef\Density{1.23}  
\section{Phase: \Phase, Density is: \Density ~-- works}
Density show: 
\pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("\Phase", \Density)}

\xdef\Phase{gas}  
\xdef\Density{0.00008}  
\section{Phase: \Phase, Density is: \Density ~-- works too}
Density show: 
\pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("\Phase", \Density)} 

\xdef\Phase{unknown}  
\xdef\Density{-1}% -1 means unknown <--- !  
\section{Phase: \Phase, Density is: \Density ~-- now works with a questionmark}
Density show: 
\pgfmathparse{DensityShowTest("\Phase", \Density)} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, very nice. Helps me good.

Comment: I will use it this way, for the normal pgfmathparse pgfmathresult syntax:
`\pgfmathdeclarefunction{DensityShowTest}{2}{%
\pgfmathparse{dim("#1")==3}%
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=1%
  \pgfmathparse{1000*#2}%
\else%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#2}{-1.0}=0 \pgfmathparse{"?"} \else\pgfmathparse{#2} \fi
\fi}`